# Regex starting with 08 number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have this regular expression that validate number and ensures the telephone number only contains numerals and spaces and is 5 digits or more. Can anyone amend this to make sure that it does not allow number starting with 08 number.

```
var telPatt = new RegExp("^$|^\\s*(?:\\d\\s*){5,}$", 'i');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the requirement by adding a negative look-ahead in the beginning:

```
var telPatt = /^(?!08)(?:\s*(?:\d\s*){5,})?$/;
```

You do not need `i` as there are no letters in your regex. Also, a literal notation is preferable. And you do not need to add alternations to allow an empty string, you can just use `?` quantifier wrapping the regex with a non-capturing group.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB9iV5/1).

Comment: Glad this solution worked for you and proved useful. Notr that lookaheads are a powerful means to restrict broader character classes and are indispensable in cases when character class subtraction is impossible and whenever there is need of adding literal exclusions. You can [read more about lookaheads at regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).